# Possible to update a row without pulling down and updating every column?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, subsonic

For examples sake, lets say I have a table containing these columns

- ID (primary key, auto increment)
- FirstName (32 characters)
- LastName (32 characters)
- Picture (binary JPEG data containing on average 10k of data)

Using SubSonic and/or LINQ how can I update only the FirstName column of a record and not try to get the Picture column or try to update the picture column?

Right now the only way I see of doing it is something like this:

```
var p=Data.People(x=>x.ID==SomeID);
p.FirstName="Foobar";
p.Save();
```

What happens over the line from what I can tell though is that it completely loads the object and completely saves the object. I don't want to have to transfer over 10k of data for such a simple operation though. How do I fix this?

Comment: Also, of course I'm aware you could just break into raw SQL, but that feels wrong.

Comment: though it has been some time but I remember that Subsonic checks for the modified columns.

Comment: @TheV yea but that doesn't help the fact that it pulls down everything in an initial `select`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an old example from Rob for a SubSonic 3 preview version.

```
db.Update<Products>().Set(
    x => x.Discontinued == false, 
    x => x.ReorderLevel == 100)
  .Where(x=>x.Category==5)
  .Execute();
```

http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/11/12/subsonic-3-0-preview-2

In your terms:

```
db.Update<People>().Set(
    p => p.FirstName == "FooBar")
  .Where(p => p.ID == SomeId)
  .Execute();
```

Comment: Actually your version doesn't compile, so I guess the first version with `==` for updating should work?

Comment: It is probably using `==` because Expression Trees do not support assignment.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't throw an error, but this does not work. The database is not changed or anything

Comment: ah nevermind, I completely forgot about the ending `.Execute()`